# custom malloc function for c

Tags: c, malloc, free

I try to write my own custom malloc and free function in c. I worked around 12 hours on this and tried lots of things. But it doesn't work.
Maybe you guys can figure out the error. Allocated memory gets removed from the list with a next pointer to a specific address to identify it later in the free function. The current error is a segmentation fault 11 in the split method.
C-File:

Head:

```
#define MAGIC ((void*)0xbaadf00d)
#define SIZE (1024*1024*1)

typedef struct mblock {
    struct mblock *next;
    size_t size;
    char memory[];
}mblock;

char memory[SIZE];

static struct mblock *head;
```

malloc:

```
void *halde_malloc (size_t size) {
    printf("Starting\n");
    printf("%zu\n",size);
    if(size <= 0) {return NULL;}
    if(head == NULL){
        initializeBlock();
        printf("Memory initialized\n");
    }
    mblock *temp_block = head;
    while(temp_block != NULL) {
        printf("IN\n");
        if(temp_block->size == size) {
            list_remove(temp_block);
            temp_block->next = MAGIC;
            return (void*)(temp_block);
        } else if(temp_block->size > size) {
            size_t temp_size = temp_block->size;
            printf("size IS more than equal\n");
            list_split_AND_Remove(temp_size - size, temp_block);
            temp_block->size = size;
            temp_block->next = MAGIC;
            return (void*)(temp_block);
        }
        temp_block = temp_block->next;
        printf("One block checked\n");
    }
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
}
```

Initialize:

```
void initializeBlock(){
    printf("Initializing\n");
    head = (mblock*)memory;
    head->size=sizeof(memory)-sizeof(mblock);
    head->next=NULL;
}
```

Split:

```
void list_split_AND_Remove(size_t size, mblock *lastBlock) {
    printf("Split\n");
    mblock *new = (void*)((mblock*)lastBlock+size+sizeof(mblock));
    new->size = size - sizeof(mblock);
    new->next = lastBlock->next;
    lastBlock->next = new;
    printf("START REMOVE");
    list_remove(lastBlock);

}
```

Remove:

```
void list_remove(mblock *p) {
    printf("Remove\n");
    mblock *temp_block = head;
    if(p == head) {
        if(head->next == NULL) {
            head = NULL;
            return;
        } else {
            head = p->next;
            return;
        }
    }
    while(temp_block->next != NULL) {
        if(temp_block->next == p) {
            printf("Found P:");
            temp_block = p->next;
            return;
        }
        temp_block = temp_block->next;
    }

}
```

Free:

```
void halde_free (void *ptr) {
    printf("FREE\n");
    mblock *new_block = ptr;
    if(new_block->next == MAGIC) {
        new_block->next = head;
        head = new_block;
    } else {abort();}

}
```

Comment: What, specifically, does "does not work" mean?  How do you elicit the misbehavior, and how does it manifest?

Comment: At this time I got a segmentation fault 11 in the split method.

Comment: Those `sizeof` are very suspicious

Comment: Anyone trying to implement their own `malloc()` should be advanced enough to know how to use a debugger and `valgrind`.

Comment: `list_remove` doesn't look right. `temp_block = p->next;` should be `temp_block->next = p->next;`

Comment: @Barmar I think its right, because temp_block->next is p, but I want to remove p from the list. So I have to connect the element before p with the element behind p.

Comment: You're not connecting anything. You're just assigning to a local variable, which will go out of scope when you `return` on the next line.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. I missed that one. Thanks. But still got the same fault.

Answer (score 3):

Issues with your code include, but are not necessarily limited to:

- `list_remove()` does not actually remove the specified block from the list unless it happens to be the current list head.  In every other case, therefore, `halde_malloc()` corrupts the list after calling `list_remove()` when it modifies the node's `next` pointer.
- `list_split_AND_Remove()` performs incorrect pointer arithmetic.  Specifically, `mblock *new = (void*)((mblock*)lastBlock+size+sizeof(mblock));` does not do what you appear to want to do, because pointer arithmetic operates in units the size of the pointed-to type, whereas the `size` argument and the result of the `sizeof` operator have units of individual bytes.  (Also, both casts are useless, albeit not harmful in themselves.)
- Your allocator returns a pointer to the block header, not to its data.  As a result, the user will very likely overwrite the block header's contents, leading to havoc when you later try to free that block.
- You seem to assume that `mblock` objects have an alignment requirement of 1.  That might not be true.